# Basic login with router

Tags: php, mvc, url-routing, framework

It's not finished yet, but I want to know if the structure and the classes are ok and what can I change. Feel free to say anything.

To be more specific, I want to know what you think about the login function in the `Login_Controller` class:

```
public function login() {
            if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                    $user = new Users_Model;

                    $username = $_POST['username'];
                    $password = $_POST['password'];

                    if ($iduser = $user->is_registered($username, $password)) {
                            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
                            $_SESSION['iduser'] = $iduser;
                            if ($_POST['keep']) {
                                    $user->save_cookie($username);
                            }
                            header('Location: ' . SITE_ROOT);
                            exit();
                    } else {
                            $error = 'El usuario o el password no son correctos.';
                            $this->main($error);
                    }
            } else {
                    $error = 'No ingreso el usuario o el password.';
                    $this->main($error);
            }
    }
```

And the router as well:

```
class Router {
    static function init($request)
    {
            $parsed = explode('/', $request);
            if ($parsed[0] == 'admin') {
                    $page = array_shift($parsed).ucfirst(array_shift($parsed));
            } else {
                    $page = array_shift($parsed);
            }
            if (empty($page)) {
                    $page = 'index';
            }
            $action = array_shift($parsed);
            if (empty($action)) {
                    $action = 'main';
            }
            if (empty($parsed)) {
                    $arguments = 0;
            } else {
                    $arguments = $parsed;
            }
            $target = SERVER_ROOT . '/controllers/' . $page . '.php';
            if (file_exists($target)) {
                    include_once $target;
                    $class = ucfirst($page) . '_Controller';
                    if (class_exists($class)) {
                            $controller = new $class;
                    } else {
                            die('la clase no existe');
                    }
            } else {
                    die('la pagina no existe');
            }
            $controller->$action($arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you get the point of MVC :(

Answer (score 1):

They are ok, but I would still do some things differently.

1. I would instead throw exceptions.
2. Instead of `if` `else` within your action, I would use a validator with rules.
3. Instead of using `$_POST/$_GET directly`, I would sanitize them and put it inside a `Request` class.
4. Error messages belongs to the view, so I would set `$view->errors[]='message'` or something like that.
5. Your routing class is not flexible. As a good example, you could take a look at the Silex framework.
6. `Login_Controller` should not exist. There might be `Account_Controller` with `login_action` or `Authenticate_Controller` with `login_action`.

Usually a Controller is a group of actions with to execute specific stuffs. For example, `Profile_Controller` has view/edit/delete action. Within the controller you check the user roles, if someone can view/edit/delete the profile. In other frameworks, they use "Access Control List (ACL)" for this purpose.

Your linked tutorial is just for the basic understanding purpose, so please don't use it. Use a readily existing framework, since you wish to build the app and not the framework itself. You might end with modifying and changing your basic structures and implementing new functions instead of developing the features of your web application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Right now I'm taking a look to the Fabien Potencier tutorial for a framework, after that I will take a look to Silex.

Comment: also please note that a Framework is just a delivery detail, it is not really required, with Clean Code Architecture which was introduced by Robert Ceciel Martin (aka. Uncle Bob) youre able to create software and switch the frameworks with less efford